# Can I use java streams api to group a map by a field in a value object and then create a new map with field as a key and original key as value

Tags: java-8, stream, hashmap, transformation

I have the following map:

```
Map<String, ImageMetaData> metadataMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Which represents the following JSON data:

```
{
  "1126901": {
    "externalRefID": "1126901",
    "docTypeKey": "10001-account",
    "imageKey": "20100203SESS20000300001",
    "scandate": "2010-02-03",
  },
  "1126902": {
    "externalRefID": "1126902",
    "docTypeKey": "10002-sig",
    "imageKey": "20100203SESS20000300004",
    "scandate": "2010-02-03",
  }
}
```

and ImageMetaData.java looks like this:

```
@Data
public class ImageMetaData {
    private String docTypeKey;
    private String externalRefID;
    private String imageKey;
    private String scandate;
}
```

Can someone suggest how can I use streams to transform `metadataMap` into:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> metadataMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Where keys are all unique `docTypeKey` (like `10001-account`) and the value is a collection of keys (like `1126901`) from the original map whose value `ImageMetaData` object has corresponding `docTypeKey` (like `10001-account`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will answer my question as I found the answer quite quickly:

```
metadataMap.values().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(metadata -> metadata.getDocTypeKey()));
```

Comment: I'd add a little improvement here by using a method ref instead of a lambda: `Collectors.groupingBy(ImageMetaData::getDocTypeKey)`